# How to limit MessageKit's input bar in details area of split view

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, inputaccessoryview, messagekit

I'm working on a messaging app which uses MessageKit. It works well on the iPhone. But, I need to support iPad screens as well. On the iPad, the input bar, which is supposed to be contained in the details (view) area, extends to the master (view) area. I need to limit the input bar on the details and a tab bar will be visible on the master. Anyone have an experience fixing this?

Here's how the input bar looks like in a sample project:
[image]

Comment: how you have added the input bar to the code

Comment: @Vinodh, I just implemented a subclass of the MessagesViewController. Basically, in the example image, DetailViewController (maroon background) is a subclass of MessagesViewController.

Comment: then you need to work on MessagesViewController to fix the inout bar on viewcontroller alone

Comment: @Vinodh, can you clarify your statement? MessagesViewController is part of MessageKit library by the way. Have you tried MessageKit before?

Comment: This is an interesting issue but is actually the expected behavior. Since you will select the input bar and the keyboard will be show across the entire screen. The library will not support this customization but it will support hiding the input bar and letting you implement your own.

Comment: @DanielLeonard, I understand that it is the expected behavior but the app I'm working on is bound to the requirement (of limiting the input bar within the details area). I think hiding the default input bar and having a way to add my own input bar sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Ya I think that is you best route. I believe I did this in a project I will have to see what I tried. But mostly what I am saying is that the library is not going to provide a way to do it and you will have to roll your one input bar solution. But the app does make a good source for how to do that.